# Organizando migrations do laravel em uma subpasta é má prática?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Criei diversas migrations que são relacionadas entre si, por terem chaves estrangeiras e etc... mas não quero misturá-las com as migrations relacionadas a auth, permissions e etc.

Minha dúvida é: Eu posso criar uma subpasta para organizar as minhas migrations dentro de database/migrations?

Desde que isso demanda um pouco mais de linhas de comando para rodar a migration de uma pasta específica, queria saber se isso é má prática e etc, pois um outro amigo meu disse que isso não é correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito não ser necessário, o esforço não compensa o retorno nesta organização, diferente de controladores, modelos e visões, que são grupos de lógica de código aos quais você retorna constantemente para trabalhar e, portanto, quanto maior e mais complexo seu sistema, mais hierarquias de organização dos arquivos podem trazer produtividade, com cada migration você trabalha uma única vez e executa sua função na alteração do banco.

Elas não devem ser "reutilizadas", inclusive executar o rollback, se necessário, será em uma única ocasião de implantação de melhoria mal sucedida.